# How to open a .csv file after user input, using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I'm very new to Python and this will be an extremely basic question.
I want a user to input the name of a csv file, which I want to open with pandas to easily access its rows and columns.
This is the code that I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd 
DATAFIN = str(raw_input("Name of your data file"))
dataset = pd.read_csv(DATAFIN)
dataset.head()
```

However, I seem to be doing some kind of mistake because this is the message I get (sorry for the lenght):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\File.py", line 34, in <module>
    dataset = pd.read_csv(DATAFIN)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
 does not exist: ' maindata.csv\r'csv
```

Do you have any idea about which is the problem?
I am sorry for any mistakes in formatting.

Comment: your code seems correct. is the file in correct directory?

Comment: @r.b.leon I believe so!

Comment: did you try dataset = pd.read_csv("nameofthefile.csv")  ? is it working ?

Comment: @r.b.leon Yes it works that way.

Comment: weird. can u please upload a screenshot of both the working one and the one you are entering file name manually?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use a space charakter in your string

```
' maindata.csv\r'
```

Try to type your csv name without the space

So it looks like

```
Name of your data filemaindata.csv
```

Comment: I just tried but it looks like the error is the same. Is it normal that when I run my program what appears is: `Name of your data file` and I write `Name of your data filemaindata.csv`? It looks weird and maybe that's my mistake, but I don't understand how else to insert the name of the file

Answer (score 0):

try to read your csv file using `pd.read_csv(r'address of the file.csv`')

Comment: That means that my user has to insert the adress of the file.csv every time and not just the name of the file?

Answer (score 0):

use argparse to get filename from command line.
run your script by `python script.py --filename file.csv`
and use print to see result

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--filename')
args = parser.parse_args()
dataset = pd.read_csv(args.filename)
print(dataset.head())
```

Comment: Hey thank you! Sorry but I'm not sure I understood correctly. I should just write your code instead of mine and but my file name where you wrote `'--filename'` ?

Comment: --filename is an argument that you define for your script and get from command line. you should replace file.csv with your filename.